# How can I create browse button for creating new file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, directory

I am creating a web application and I need when I click a button to browse the folders on the computer and create new file in the chosen folder with the specified name. How can I do that using C# and ASP.NET?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions. "Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this link](http://support2.microsoft.com/?ID=KB;EN-US;q306654&lex) there's an example of this using PDF files. A code snippet found there:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
             //Set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
             //Get the physical path to the file.
        string FilePath = MapPath("acrobat.pdf");
             //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
            Response.End();
    }
```

An example of the code above in use(found [here](http://aspalliance.com/259)):

```
private void DownloadFile( string fname, bool forceDownload )
{
  string path = MapPath( fname );
  string name = Path.GetFileName( path );
  string ext = Path.GetExtension( path );
  string type = "";
  // set known types based on file extension  
  if ( ext != null )
  {
    switch( ext.ToLower() )
    {
    case ".htm":
    case ".html":
      type = "text/HTML";
      break;

    case ".txt":
      type = "text/plain";
      break;

    case ".doc":
    case ".rtf":
      type = "Application/msword";
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( forceDownload )
  {
    Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + name );
  }
  if ( type != "" )   
    Response.ContentType = type;
  Response.WriteFile( path );
  Response.End();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By its very nature, ASP.NET at best has a file upload control.  This is not supported natively.  You need to look for something to do this: maybe Silverlight would do the job, or look for a third-party component, or maybe a JavaScript utility framework.  I'm not sure what allows you to create a file out of the box.